# Multiple Paths confusion when designing REST API

Tags: node.js, rest, api, swagger, swagger-codegen

We have a resources named Games and Players

```
/games -> Get all Games available

/games/{game-id} -> Get the game details of specific Game with game-id

/players/me -> Get logged in Player details
```

There will be Games played by the player which can be tagged under Games or Players

---

**Scenario 1**

`/games/me -> Fetches games played by the current logged in player`

This groups the request under Games tag. I'm using Swagger API so this call will be going to GamesAPI controller on the client generated code. I see its fair to be in the Games api rather than player as its related to games.

**Problem** : It looks too odd to consider "me" as a special id as it looks it is one form of {game-id} which I can't digest.

---

**Scenario 2**

```
/players/me/games -> Fetches games played by the current logged in player
```

This groups it under Player tag which goes to PlayerAPI after code generation. The path has a meaning which is good but, its more relevant to have it in GamesAPI (by my choice - I could be wrong, please suggest)

Among these two scenarios which is the better way to design this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it.

As mentioned with Scenario 1, I see "me" conflicts with {game-id} and confuses users.
With Scenario 2, I see fetching user games from player API isn't intuitive.

So I went with an approach where it tries to keep the endpoints minimal.
I added a new query parameter "playedOnly:boolean" for GET /games which returns all the games related to the player.

This simplifies lot of things. I can still go with /games endpoint and no more confusion!

Answer (score 0):

Scenario 1 seems to be better among two because in general your games url will land to GameController and there you can have action function for fetching all games, one game of given id, or the logged in user's games.

Answer (score 0):

Relationship design is driven in API's how your schema's are designed .So, in your case

1 Player can play 1 or Many games - So **1 to Many** relationship

Hence, you should be grouping game data based of players . So, 2 scenarios arise for an API to have better performance

**Scenario 1**

Is it easier to search in Games for the player id and then group them?

**Scenario 2**

Is it easier to search Players on the basis of the Game id and then group them?

Logically, speaking and considering scenario 1 makes more sense , hence

```
/games/{player-id} -> Fetches games played by the current logged in player
```

Comment: /games/{player-id} -> but this conflicts with GET /games/{game-id}

Comment: @Ayyappa how does ?, this will get you the game for the player-id where as ` /games/{game-id}`
gives you the game per game-id

Comment: Thats not how it works. {player-id} or {game-id} can be any id or alpha numeric value. It's tough to classify or group all documents/records under same resource just by id alone.